# How to keep track with std::forward_list 's first element?

Tags: c++, iterator, forward-list

I want to save an iterator of the first elements in a forward list as `it` and do some insert on the list. Then I want to erase the element at `it`.
For example, in {20,30,40,50} and insert 10 at front. We get {10,20,30,40,50}. Then I want to erase 20, which means I want {10,30,40,50}.
I tried to use `before_begin()` but it seems that it always point to the before of `begin()` of the list even after inserting.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    forward_list<int> fl = { 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    auto it = fl.before_begin();
    fl.emplace_front(10);
    fl.erase_after(it);
    cout << "Element of the list are:" << endl;
    for (auto it = fl.begin(); it != fl.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Have 20,30,40,50 rather than 10,30,40,50.

Is there any way to store a inerator that after `++`, it will point to the begin element.

Comment: That's what `before_begin` exists for. It points to "nothing" originally, but advance it one element, and it becomes the `begin` element. By definition there is no other iterator that works this way, and since it's definitionally before `begin`, if you push on a new front element, it remains before that element. If you want to erase the element after the new element, you need to either manually advance the iterator or just get `.begin()` again. `forward_list` is *very* bare bones (to keep it on par with a minimalist singly-linked list written by hand in C), you're responsible for more here.

Comment: If I read you correctly, you want to delete the original first element (now second element) after inserting a new first element. What exactly is wrong with calling `fl.erase_after(fl.begin());` or `fl.erase_after(++it);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by adding an `count`, counting the number inserted at `front` and then move iterators from `begin()`.